# Unable to connect AWS RDS MySQL from public IP of EC2 isntance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, database-connection, aws-security-group

From my EC2 instance, I am able to connect to MySQL AWS RDS instance with `mysql` command as shown below *if* the RDS security group allows traffic from anywhere on port `3306`. However, if I set the VPC default security group (also attached to the RDS instance) to accept `3306` traffic *only* from the public IP address of this EC2 instance, then the connection does not go through.

```sh
export MYSQ_PWD=password
mysql -h AWS_RDS_HOST -P 3306 -u admin
```

The EC2 and RDS instances are part of testing some functionalities of our application and required to be fully automated and 'throwaway' in nature. However, I don't want to keep the access as wide as `0.0.0.0/0` but limit to the IP address of the EC2 instance. The IP address of the EC2 instance is derived from `curl -s http://checkip.amazonaws.com/`.

Comment: Is the RDS instance configured to be "publicly accessible"? I assume the EC2 and RDS instances are in the same VPC? Have you tried using the EC2 instance's private IP address instead of the public IP address?

Comment: RDS is publicly accessible. Yes, EC2 and RDS are in same VPC. Yes, tried private IP address too.